# Make rspec tests run in parallel on GPU

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gpu

Could we some how execute rspec tests on GPU in parrallel? For example https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests do that i need but on CPU.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if rspec is supported but if you use JRuby -- you can parallelize ruby code on GPUs using the "barracuda" gem (it supports OpenCL currently)